# Compile the wlua.exe

Tags: windows, lua, cl

How do I compile the `wlua.exe` interpreter using `cl.exe`?
I compile the Lua with the following command:

```
cl /MD /O2 /c /DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL *.c
ren lua.obj lua.o
ren luac.obj luac.o
link /DLL /IMPLIB:lua5.3.lib /OUT:lua5.3.dll *.obj
link /OUT:lua.exe lua.o lua5.3.lib
lib /OUT:lua5.3-static.lib *.obj
link /OUT:luac.exe luac.o lua5.3-static.lib
```